# sqlalchemy with_for_update cause that select not working in session

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, celery

I'm using flask+mysql and celery+redis.

I have a `Backend` and `Item` models with `ForeignKey` relation.

I have the similar code like below that I'm running in task:

```
@task()
def my_task():
  while True:
    backends = db.session.query(Backend).filter(Item.in_use==False)

    for backend in backends:
       # do some staff

       # select Item again and set it in_use
       try:
           item = db.session.query(
               Item
           ).with_for_update().filter_by(
               backend=backend,
               in_use=False
            ).order_by(func.rand()).first()
            if item:
                item.in_use = True
                backend.usage = Backend.usage+1
                db.session.add(item)
                db.session.add(backend)
                db.session.commit()
       except exc.OperationalError as e:
          # catching deadlock
          pass

       db.session.commit()
    time.sleep(30)
    if item:
       item.in_use = False
       db.session.add(item)
       db.session.commit()
       break
```

If i run it 5-10 tasks parallel it works fine. But when I launch 100 tasks at the end I have 10-15 tasks that will work forever. Because query:

```
backends = db.session.query(Backend).filter(Item.in_use==False)
```

Returns always 0 free `Backends`.

In **MYSQL** I see that all Items been released. I can save them, change status, but queries inside task keep returning 0 `Items`

I launch task like this:

```
@task
def run_tasks():
    g = group(my_task.s() for _ in range(0, count))
    g()

run_tasks.delay()
```

If I will do:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

I see some sleep processes.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why you do order(`order_by(func.rand()`)?